# hide span text for a button on responsive web design

Tags: html

want to hide the "Receive text" on responsive web design. tried with display:none property of css on span class but not working.want to show only the glyphicon in small screen.Any idea that works would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

```css
.btnReceive span-text
{
    display: none !important;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnReceive" class="btnReceive" type="submit"  runat="server" visible="false"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-Envelope"></i> <span class="text">Receive</span></button></li>
```

Comment: There is no such element as `<span-text>` – you probably meant `span.text`. Vote to close, since this is just a mere typo.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the correct tag in the CSS. Which would be `span` not `span-text`.
I have added some text 'glyphicon' to the `i` element as we dont have bootstrap included it wouldnt be replaced by the icon. Just so you can see that it is being shown but the `span` is not. You also don't need `!important` or `visibility:hidden` once you have used the correct selector.

```css
.btnReceive span
{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnReceive" class="btnReceive" type="submit"  runat="server" visible="false"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-Envelope">glyphicon</i> <span class="text">Receive</span></button>
```

For the 'on small screen' bit you are going to have to update your question with a little more information. What screen width? You will need to use media queries here and the viewport meta tag. For example this media query will add your CSS for screens less than 320px width.

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 320px) {
    .btnReceive span{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

You can change the `320px` to a width you would like. Be sure to add the viewport meta tag for this to take effect on mobile devices.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Im sure this is probably just a copy and paste error but also not sure if you have noticed you have an erroneous `li` tag at the end of your `button` tag.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.btnReceive span.text
{
    display: none 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your CSS tag and use it inside a media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) {

    .btnReceive span {
         display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all  for your help